# Heroku Foreman Exits on Express.js bodyParser() call

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express, foreman

When running foreman start, I see the following message

```
> foreman start
20:38:55 web.1  | started with pid 3896
20:38:55 web.1  | Development
20:38:56 web.1  | connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
20:38:56 web.1  | exited with code 1
20:38:56 system | sending SIGKILL to all processes
```

I was wondering why this was the case, since running `node server.js` does not appear to terminate the server.

Here is the segment of code that appears to cause the app to terminate with exit code 1:

```
var app = express();
app.configure(function()
{
    // More config things above
    app.use(express.bodyParser());   // This line is causing the issue
    // More config things below
}
```

The above is code using the [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) framework. Removing the above call to express.bodyParser() allows the server to run (via foreman). The problem is, I'll need the body parser module in order to parse my incoming get/posts requests.

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea why foreman exits when deprecation warning is reported in express, but you can eliminate this behavior replacing `app.use(express.bodyParser());` with

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

`connect.multipart()` will be removed from `bodyParser`in next version of Connect and this is probably the issue. You can find more info in [Connect documenattion](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) and/or in [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581146/how-to-get-rid-of-connect-3-0-deprecation-alert).

Comment: `bodyParser() = json() + urlencoded() + multipart()`. if you're not using file uploads, no need to include `multipart()` middleware. Even if you use file uploads you can use `formidable` or any other module to handle file uploads.

Comment: @vmx, do you know of any examples that utilize formidable explicitly as an express/connect module (it's used in bodyParser, I believe)

Comment: multipart() is considered a security issue when used as a general middleware, it is better to use formidable to explicitly handle file upload as @vmx pointed out