# Body is undefined when parsing JSON in Express.js

Tags: json, node.js, express

I have a simple server where i just prints a json to the screen when its posted. This is my code:

```
/*jslint node:true*/

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(app.router);

app.post('/event', function (res, req) {
    //'use strict';
    console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Then i put a JSON to the server with curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:3000/event
```

But the server just prints `undefined`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Add app.use(express.bodyParser()); immediately after app.use(app.router);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out what the problem is. It should be:

```
function (req, res)
```

and not:

```
function (res, req)
```

since the first parameter is the request and the second is the response.

Comment: you didn't even include that part in your question!

Answer (score 5):

you haven't defined usage of 
express.bodyParser()

it has to be done like this:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

live example:
module routes file

```
exports.post = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    //res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

application:

```
app.post('/post', routes.post);
```

fiddler request:

[image]

from comments: in case you have latest libs, you should take into account that bodyParser is deprecated from Connect 3.0. appropriate thread: [How to get rid of Connect 3.0 deprecation alert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581146/how-to-get-rid-of-connect-3-0-deprecation-alert/19611997#19611997)

Comment: Should i do that instaid of `express.json()`?

Comment: yes. intead. take a look there a more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005939/how-to-consume-json-post-data-in-an-express-application

Comment: good point but it's based on version of libs. I will add it to answer