# app is not initialized in node express

Tags: node.js, express

I have just installed node and express. When I run the comman `node app.js` it gives me following error.

```
   connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
   visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
   connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
   /var/www/nodeexpress/nodetest1/app.js:38
   console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().
                                                                ^
  TypeError: undefined is not a function
  at Server.<anonymous> (/var/www/nodeexpress/nodetest1/app.js:38:69)
  at Server.g (events.js:196:16)
  at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:101:17)
  at net.js:1159:10
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:339:11)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:492:11)
  at startup (node.js:124:16)
  at node.js:803:3
```

And My app.js looks like

```
 var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes');

//var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
var app = express();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'your secret here' }));
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);

app.listen(8080, function(){
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port,    app.settings.env);
});
```

It seems that express not getting initalized. My node version is `v0.11.13-pre` and I hav0.11.13-pree installed express version using package.json as `3.4.4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **this.address().port**  than **app.address().port**

address() is a function property of the http object to which the *listen* function is applied

From connect proto.js:

```
app.listen = function(){
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

as for the connect.multipart() warning, check this answer: [How to get rid of Connect 3.0 deprecation alert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581146/how-to-get-rid-of-connect-3-0-deprecation-alert)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

You need to remove this line because the bodyParser method is not in this version.

**app.use(express.bodyParser());**

replace with

**app.use(express.json());**

**app.use(express.urlencoded());**

Let me know if still facing any issue.